# SQL Syntax for selecting the ID column and latest date from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union, distinct

I have a system where users can complete two types of tests. I need to get a list of `DISTINCT` users sorted by the date of their latest test completion.

For this purpose the tables may as well be set out as:

```
Test_Users
 - Test_User_Id (int)

Test_1_Results
 - Test_1_Result_Id (int)
 - Test_User_Id (int)
 - Date_Of_Completion (datetime)

Test_2_Results
 - Test_2_Result_Id (int)
 - Test_User_Id (int)
 - Date_Of_Completion (datetime)
```

I can happily get a list of all the different `Test_User_Id`'s using a `UNION` as follows:

```
SELECT Test_User_Id FROM Test_1_Results
UNION
SELECT Test_User_Id FROM Test_2_Results
```

And I could easily sort the results from one of these tables using a `ORDER BY Date_Of_Completion DESC` but i do not know how to do this with the `UNION` or if this is even the best way to proceed.

Ultimately i would like to be able to wrap this query within others like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_Users
WHERE Test_User_Id IN (
    //The query i am asking about
)
WHERE some_criteria
```

But so far i haven't had any luck doing this while using a `UNION` and i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

The reason i am trying to do this is that the admin user needs to be able to view a list of everyone who has completed their tests with the most recent completions at the top.

I am fairly familiar with SQL, but i have never really had to use the `UNION` operator before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
 SELECT Test_User_Id, max(Date_Of_Completion) AS doc
 FROM ( 
     SELECT Test_User_Id, Date_Of_Completion FROM Test_1_Results
       UNION ALL
     SELECT Test_User_Id , Date_Of_Completion FROM Test_2_Results 
 ) AS temptab
 GROUP BY Test_User_Id
 ORDER BY doc DESC
```

Comment: +1, But I would change UNION to UNION ALL because I think it would perform better.

Comment: Thanks, will try this shortly, looks promising. @dbenham i assume that the performance benefit of `UNION ALL` is due to not having to look for and remove duplicates? Which is being done by the `GROUP BY` anyway, so this saves us doing it twice?

Comment: Works perfectly, turns our the bit i was missing from my own attempts was the `AS temptab` bit.

Comment: @Ben - Yes, removing duplicates with UNION is a waste of time in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH x(u,d) AS 
(
  SELECT u = Test_User_Id, d = MAX(Date_Of_Completion) 
    FROM dbo.Test_1_Results GROUP BY Test_User_Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Test_User_Id, MAX(Date_Of_Completion) 
    FROM dbo.Test_2_Results GROUP BY Test_User_Id
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT u, d, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u ORDER BY d DESC)
  FROM x
)
SELECT Test_User_Id = u, Date_Of_Completion = d
FROM y
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Test_User_Id, max(Date_Of_Completion)
FROM Test_Users t
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Test_User_Id, Date_Of_Completion FROM Test_1_Results
    UNION
    SELECT Test_User_Id, Date_Of_Completion FROM Test_2_Results) aux on aux.Test_User_Id = t.Test_User_Id
GROUP BY t.Test_User_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the ejb_guy answer for the original question. If the question is extended such that you also want to know the Test Type and Result ID for the most recent result for each user, then I believe the following will work (untested), and it should be very efficient.

```
with All_Tests as (
  select Test_User_Id,
         Date_Of_Completion,
         'Test1' as Test_Type,
         Test_1_Result_Id as Result_Id
    from Test_1_Results
  union all
  select Test_User_Id,
         Date_Of_Completion,
         'Test2' as Test_Type,
         Test_2_Result_Id as Result_Id
    from Test_2_Results
),
Ranked_Tests as (
  select rank() over( partition by Test_User_Id
                      order by Date_Of_Completion desc,
                               Test_Type,
                               Result_Id
                    ) as Test_Rank,
         Test_User_Id,
         Date_Of_Completion,
         Test_Type,
         Result_Id
    from All_Tests
)
select Test_User_Id,
       Date_Of_Completion,
       Test_Type,
       Result_Id
  from Ranked_Tests
 where Test_Rank=1
 order by Date_Of_Completion desc, Test_User_Id
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that is something that i was thinking about including as well!